# Programmatically changing a winforms button text color doesn't work

Tags: c#, winforms

When I try to programmatically change a button's text color on my winforms form, it doesn't work. I have this code:

```
btnTestConnection.Text = "Valid connection";
btnTestConnection.Font = new Font(btnTestConnection.Font, FontStyle.Bold);
btnTestConnection.BackColor = Color.Green;
btnTestConnection.ForeColor = Color.White;
```

1. The text changes as expected.
2. The font changes to bold as expected.
3. The BackColor changes to green as expected.
4. The ForeColor remains black - unchanged.

This seems bizarre. I have verified that nothing downstream changes the forecolor back to black. What am I missing?

I am using VS 2017 and compiling my project against .NET Framework 4.5.2.

Answer (score 4):

I figured it out. My button is disabled at the time the ForeColor property is being set to white. Apparently winforms won't allow a disabled button to have its ForeColor property changed.